# Realm Filesize varies though same data is saved

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am writing an iOS-App that stores sites. Each of the sites has a different address. For a test I created 32k sites and also 32k addresses. When I first created all those datapoint the realm file took up about 9gb of data. To be sure about the amount of space that it takes to store this data I rerun the test several times.

Every time I ran these test, the file size was different, in a range from 25mb to 10gb. I am not sure though, what the problem seems to be. Are there any suggestions what I might look for?

Comment: You're definitely not closing your Realm instance on the background thread. You *might* be using multiple transactions instead of just one transaction.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you're partly right. I was indeed using multiple transactions, however there is, as far as I know, no way to close a realm instance in swift

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Could you explain to me why, the size gets so big and so random in that case. Because as I thought it doesn't matter if I write in multiple transactions or just in one?

Comment: It appears you are correct, the Realm instance is autoclosed in swift if the references are nulled out. But my wild guess is that Realms autoupdate only on looping threads like the UI thread, so using many (concurrent) transactions on background threads create retained outdated versions that the background thread continues to hold on to in its open Realm instance which can only be removed by compacting the Realm.

Comment: Yes, that is the same with Realm on iOS. To avoid old versions being pinned you should perform your work that uses Realm inside an autoreleasepool when working on a dispatch queue or background thread that's not running a runloop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am more well-versed in Realm-java than Realm-Swift, but if you retain old instances of a Realm that belong to non-looping threads that cannot update themselves (in swift world, apparently that's background threads and dispatch queues), you need to close the Realm instance, and in swift, you need to wrap your Realm in an [autoreleasepool](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) in order to auto-close it. Here is the relevant [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#using-a-realm-across-threads) regarding this behavior.

> The intermediate versions of data in the Realm file cannot be reused until the Realm object is deallocated. To avoid this issue, you should use an explicit autorelease pool when accessing a Realm from a dispatch queue.

I also think it helps if you reduce the number of transactions you execute on a given background thread.

The old versions that ended up getting retained take up additional space, this can be compacted using `compactRealm`. For that to work, all instances of the Realm need to be closed on every thread.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that helps me a lot

Answer (score 2):

If the file size is significantly larger than the amount of data you're storing, it's likely you're running into an issue termed [version pinning](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#file-size--tracking-of-intermediate-versions).

Version pinning is when a `Realm` instance stays around for much longer than expected while other threads are writing new data. A `Realm` instance keeps alive the version of the data it's looking at until it is deallocated or refreshed to the latest version. If one thread is writing data to the Realm while another thread has a `Realm` instance open at an older version, the new data cannot overwrite the old and so the file size ends up growing. When the `Realm` instance is deallocated or advanced to the current version, the space for the older versions within the Realm file is marked as free and can be reused for subsequent writes.

One common situation that can result in version pinning is when using Realm on dispatch queues, and a `Realm` instance ends up in a dispatch queue's autorelease pool. Dispatch queues drain their autorelease pools relatively infrequently which can result in the lifetime of the `Realm` instance being significantly longer than you might expect. To avoid this class of issue we suggest that all work involving Realm on dispatch queues be explicitly wrapped in autorelease pools. This will ensure that the `Realm` instances are released in a timely manner.

Comment: The answer is in fact right as well, but unfortunately I'm not able to accept two, and as the other one was first, I accepted that one